# Application Working on Browser but not in Android Phone - App

Tags: javascript, android, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap, onsen-ui

I recently developed the app using HTML, CSS, JS, Firebase and Onsen UI, it is a simple app that pulls the quotes from Firebase and displays it on the main page as categories first and then upon clicking will load the quotes specific to the category.

1. This application works perfectly fine in the browser, but I built the app on online Phonegap via the below git, but the app is not loading the Categories on the main page at all. Checked for the whitelisting, that is sorted as well I guess, please check config.xml
2. Side menu has different menus, but only Add Quote is functional, the UI is coming up, but adding is not happening on the App (works fine in the browser)

**Request someone to help me out here.**

1. Am I doing this right?
2. Any Onsen framework expert - who can assist me with the back button feature on this app - I am not able to code it.
3. Am I missing something?
4. For online phonegap - is it important to put all the files/folders in www first?

https://github.com/santosh610610/finalTest

Answer (score 0):

When you're building a Phonegap app, your code needs to be in the `www` folder. So, in your repository, you will need to create a `www` folder. Then move `img`, `lib`, `index.html` and `index2.html` in there.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance! I updated the repo and rebuilt it, but it is the same. I still don't see the category list on the home page upon starting the application. And also when I am adding the quote by using the Add Quote page, it is not functioning. In the browser when I add it works fine and displays the added quote on the UI and updates Firebase in the backend. That is not happening on the the App. Can you please help here. Here is the new repo - https://github.com/santosh610610/QuotesApp

Comment: Your `config.xml` and `res` folder should _not_ be inside the `www` folder. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Tried this @stransen, its the same thing. I am looking at the repos to find more about this. But as you said, the files mentioned should be out of www folder. Thank you!